# RSA Implemenations

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I'm working on a rsa implementation. I am pretty much finished I would think, I'm having an occasional error where when I run my code, this is the error that pop up in the shell:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/damion/Documents/projects/project2.py", line 164, in <module>
  decrypt_message = decrypt(encrypted_message,d,n)# decrypt message that was encrypted.
File "/home/damion/Documents/projects/project2.py", line 115, in decrypt
  decrypt_string+=DecimalToChar(m)#add each charactor to a string
File "/home/damion/Documents/projects/project2.py", line 96, in DecimalToChar
  return str(chr(d))
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

and this is my code:

```
from random import randint

def prime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True

def isprime(n):
    """
        return true if n is a prime number and false otherwise"""
    if prime(n):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def prime_generator():
    primeone=12
    while not isprime(primeone):
        primeone=randint(11,5000)
        print primeone
    print "prime number is: "+str(primeone)

    primetwo = primeone
    primetwo+=1
    while not isprime(primetwo):
        primetwo+=1
    print primetwo
    return primeone,primetwo

def gcd(x,y):
    """
        use to calculate the greatest common divisible of x and y """
    if y == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return gcd(y,x%y)

def n(prime1,prime2):
    """
        calculte and return 'N' That is used to find phi(N),and that is also used as to
        make up the private and public key
        """
    return prime1*prime2

def caculatePhi(prime1,prime2):
    """
        calculate Phi(N) and return Phi(N)"""
    return (prime1-1)*(prime2-1)

def e_finder(e,phi):
    """
        calculate e for the public key and return Phi(n),e,n"""
    while True:
        if gcd(phi,e) == 1:# check to see if phi and e has no common factor except one(1)
            return e
        else:
            e +=2 #increment e by to if there is a gcd>1

def Extended_Euclidean_Algorithm(PHI, E):
    phi = PHI
    e = E
    A,X,previous_X,Y,previous_Y = phi,0,1,1,0
    while e != 0:

        temp = e
        quotient = int(phi/e)
        e = phi % e
        phi = temp

        temp = X
        phi = previous_X - quotient * X
        previous_X = temp

        temp = Y
        Y = previous_Y - quotient * Y
        previous_Y = temp

    return A + previous_Y


def generate_keys(E,D,N):
    e,d,n = E,D,N
    """Calcualte private key(d),generate keys and return these keys
        ie. public and private keys for encryption and decryption"""

    return {"public_key":{"e":e,"n":n}},{"private_key":{"d":d,"n":n}}

def CharToDecimal(char):
    """convert a charactor to its decimal value
        """
    c=char
    return int(ord(c))

def DecimalToChar(decimal):
    d=decimal
    return str(chr(d))


def encrypt(m,e,n):
    """encrypt message and return that encrypted message """
    encryped_string = ""
    encrypt_lst=[]
    for i in m:# loop through message, getting charactor at a time for encryption
        m_char = CharToDecimal(i)#convert each charactor to its decimal equivalent
        c=pow(m_char,e,n)#equivalent to c=(m**e)%n
        encrypt_lst.append(c) # add each encrypted charactor to a LIST
        encryped_string+=str(c)
    return encrypt_lst,encryped_string

def decrypt(c,d,n):
    """decrypt message and return that decrypted message"""
    decrypt_string = ""
    for i in c: #loop through LIST of encrypted values,for decryption index by index 
        m=pow(i,d,n)#equivalent to m=(i**d)%n
        decrypt_string+=DecimalToChar(m)#add each charactor to a string
    return decrypt_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Main for excuting programme"""
    message = str(raw_input("Enter message to encrypt: "))
##    prime_one = int(raw_input("Please Enter First Prime Number: "))
##    prime_two = int(raw_input("Please Enter Second Prime Number: "))
##
    prime_one,prime_two = prime_generator()
    while (not isprime(prime_one) or not isprime(prime_two)):#prompt user to enter value if not prime
        print""
        print""
        print"_________________________________________________________"
        if not isprime(prime_one):print "first number was not prime!!!"
        if not isprime(prime_two):print "Second number was not prime!!!"
        print""
        print"_________________________________________________________"
        print""
        prime_one = int(raw_input("Please enter first prime nuber: "))
        prime_two = int(raw_input("Please enter second prime : "))


    while prime_one<11 or prime_two<11: # prompt user to re-enter prime if less than 11
        print""
        print""
        print"_________________________________________________________"
        if prime_one<11:print "first number  Must Be greater Than 10!!!"
        if prime_two<11:print "Second number Must Be greater Than 10!!!"
        print""
        print"_________________________________________________________"
        print""
        prime_one = int(raw_input("Please enter first prime nuber: "))
        prime_two = int(raw_input("Please enter second prime : "))

    n= n(prime_one,prime_two)
    phi = caculatePhi(prime_one,prime_two)
    e=e_finder(3,phi)
    d=Extended_Euclidean_Algorithm(phi,e)


    keys = generate_keys(e,d,n) #get generated keys(public and private) and store them in keys

    print "keys are: ",keys


    encrypted_message,encryped_string = encrypt(message,e,n)#encrypt message from user
    print "Encrypted string: "+str(encryped_string)#display string of encrypted input
    print encrypted_message
    decrypt_message = decrypt(encrypted_message,d,n)# decrypt message that was encrypted.
    print "Our message decrypted is: "+str(decrypt_message)
```

Comment: please any help will do, a point in the right direction is all i need

Comment: Please try and format your question and code yourself. I can understand if English is not your native tongue, but lowercase "im" instead of "I am" seems to be just laziness to me. You cannot just designate everything a code-snippet. Only designate it to be a code snippet if it can actually run as one. Also make clear by a comment where the exception occurs, and what you have done to debug your code...

Comment: The reason is obvious from the exception - d is over 256 or below 0. Put a breakpoint and debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Korem said, you're passing an illegal value to `chr`, in the `DecimalToChar` function.  (The stack trace is your friend.  *Read* the stack trace.)  `DecimalToChar` is just a big, fat wrapper around `chr`, which in Python 2 only accepts an unsigned, one-byte integer (0 through 255, inclusive).

You call `DecimalToChar` in exactly one place, with the argument `m`:

```
m=pow(i,d,n)#equivalent to m=(i**d)%n
```

This will produce legal input to `chr` only by chance (and pretty rare chance at that: `i ** d` is likely large, and `n` is the product of two large prime numbers.)

The traditional way to ensure an unknown (non-negative) integer is within a given range is modular division, in this case something like:

```
def DecimalToChar(decimal):
    d=decimal % 256
    return str(chr(d))
```

This will avoid the error you ran into, but I don't think it will fix your program.  A bigger question is:  **Why do you think `m` should be a valid ASCII byte in the first place?**

A few other suggestions:

1. You have a *lot* of code in the global namespace.  (In fact, you trash your `n`-the-function when you reuse that name for `n`-the-product-of-two-large-primes.  This is a bug.)  Get all that mess into a proper `main` function.
2. You have a lot of functions that don't really *do* anything.  `n` is one (with a uselessly cryptic name to boot), as are `CharToDecimal` and `DecimalToChar`, which duplicate Python builtins but require more typing.
3. You have a lot of code that does literally nothing.  The aforementioned `CharToDecimal` calls `int` on the output of `ord`, which is *always* an integer, while `DecimalToChar` calls `str` on the output of `chr`, which is always a string.  (They also rename their parameters for absolutely no reason.)  `isprime` just returns whatever `prime` would have.  Do-nothing code like this can contain bugs, but it can never help you.
4. CONSISTENCY!  Your function and variable names, whitespace, docstrings, and even comment formatting are all over the place.  This will hide bugs by making your good code and your bad code look equally bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin J. Chase and  @Korem, I followed the instructions I got from you guys and things seem to be working. I am kind of new to programming as I relates to out side school setting, so thanks again.